# How do I set print quality using DYMO label framework?

Tags: vb.net, dymo

In the DYMO Label Software v8, you go to edit > preferences > labelWriter printer and select 'text' as print quality to reduce print quality which increases print speed.

However, how do I do this when sending a label to the printer from my VB.Net app using the SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dymo developer answered my question on the DYMO Developer website:

> You can use the [LabelWriterPrintParams](http://www.labelwriter.com/software/dls/sdk/docs/DYMOLabelFrameworkdotNETHelp/html/T_DYMO_Label_Framework_ILabelWriterPrintParams.htm) class to set the graphics mode that adjusts the printed resolution.

Basically, the following lines will do the trick for vb.net:

```
Dim printParams As LabelWriterPrintParams = New LabelWriterPrintParams
printParams.PrintQuality = LabelWriterPrintQuality.Text

Label.Print(printer, printParams)
```